# How to present a view controller from appdelegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been searching all day on how to present a view controller from within the appdelegate.  It appears that in xcode 11 the window property was moved to the scenedelegate which has been confusing me.  I want to present a view controller from within the appdelegate from the didReceiveRemoteNotification function so when the user receives a notification it takes them to a  separate view controller with information.  I have tried to do:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(LoginViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

within the appdelegate which used to work in a previous application of mine but it does not seem to work anymore.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the hard part presenting the view controller, or is it receiving the remote notification?

Comment: You can get the `connectedScenes` from the `UIApplication` object. You will need to pick one to show the new view controller.

Comment: The hard part is presenting the view controller.  I am able to receive notifications.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue by using shared windows to get the window from scenedelegate to present the view controller on.

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This hasn't been a good approach since iOS 13. And `UIApplication windows` has been deprecated since iOS 15. This solution may fail in apps supporting multiple scenes on an iPad. It may also fail if the found controller is already presenting another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach to present view controller through app delegate is without falling for hierarchy like below:

```swift
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "YOURSTORYBOARDNAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOURVIEWCONTROLLER") as? YOURVIEWCONTROLLER {
    if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
        var currentController = rootViewController
        while let presentController = currentController.presentedViewController {
            currentController = presentController
        }
        currentController.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using storyboard.